# How to create index column for set of values in other column

Tags: r, function, dataframe, indexing, data.table

I have a dataframe:

```
ID      operation
A1       open
A1       open
A1       close
A1       
A1       open
A1       close
B2      
B2       open
B2       open
B2       open
B2       close
B2       upload
B2       open
B2       close
B2       open
B2       close
```

I want to add index for each bundle of "open" and "close" in column operation. So for each row between open and close must have same index. So desired result is:

```
ID      operation    index
A1       open         1
A1       open         1
A1       close        1
A1       
A1       open         2
A1       close        2
B2      
B2       open         3
B2       open         3
B2       open         3
B2       close        3
B2       upload
B2       open         4
B2       close        4
B2       open         5
B2       close        5
```

How could i do that? Which function could be used for these and how to apply it? Preferably by using data.table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way to do it in `data.table`:

```
dt[, index := .GRP, by = .(rev(cumsum(rev(operation) == 'close')))]
dt[, index := ifelse(cumsum(operation == 'open') > 0, index, NA), by = .(ID, index)]
dt
#     ID operation index
#  1: A1      open     1
#  2: A1      open     1
#  3: A1     close     1
#  4: A1              NA
#  5: A1      open     2
#  6: A1     close     2
#  7: B2              NA
#  8: B2      open     3
#  9: B2      open     3
# 10: B2      open     3
# 11: B2     close     3
# 12: B2    upload    NA
# 13: B2      open     4
# 14: B2     close     4
# 15: B2      open     5
# 16: B2     close     5
```

Due to the two path of `cumsum`, if an operation is not in `c('open', 'close')`, it will:

- get an correct index if it is between `open` and `close`;
- get `NA` if it is between `close` and `open`.

Comment: Fascinating answer! It took me a while to understand this but kudos.  Thanks for sharing

Comment: and is it possible to add another option of value with "close"? like to make "close" or "checking"?

Comment: @reredf, try to ask a new question. The dataframe is unreadable in comment.

Comment: @mt1022 and how to make this index be grouped by ID? So for each ID it starts from scratch (1,2,3,...)?this didn't work ```dt[, index := .GRP, by = .(ID, rev(cumsum(rev(operation) == 'close')))]```

Comment: @reredf, `dt[!is.na(index), index := rleid(index), by = .(ID)]`.

Comment: yes, you can see my answer to your new question.

Answer (score 1):

Taking leads from the **mt1022's** fantastic solution, I am translating the answer for `dplyr` users

```
df %>% mutate(index = dense_rank(-rev(cumsum(rev(operation) == 'close')))) %>%
  group_by(ID, index) %>% mutate(index = ifelse(cumsum(operation == 'open') > 0, index, NA)) %>%
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 16 x 3
   ID    operation index
   <chr> <chr>     <int>
 1 A1    open          1
 2 A1    open          1
 3 A1    close         1
 4 A1    <NA>         NA
 5 A1    open          2
 6 A1    close         2
 7 B2    <NA>         NA
 8 B2    open          3
 9 B2    open          3
10 B2    open          3
11 B2    close         3
12 B2    upload       NA
13 B2    open          4
14 B2    close         4
15 B2    open          5
16 B2    close         5
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution with `for` loop :

```
df$index <- NA
index <- 0
flag <- FALSE

for(i in seq_len(nrow(df))) {
  if(df$operation[i] == '') next
  else if(df$operation[i] == 'open' & !flag) {
    index <- index + 1
    flag <- TRUE
  }
  else if(df$operation[i] == 'close' & flag) flag <- FALSE
  df$index[i] <- index
}
df

#   ID operation index
#1  A1      open     1
#2  A1      open     1
#3  A1     close     1
#4  A1              NA
#5  A1      open     2
#6  A1     close     2
#7  B2              NA
#8  B2      open     3
#9  B2      open     3
#10 B2      open     3
#11 B2     close     3
#12 B2      open     4
#13 B2     close     4
#14 B2      open     5
#15 B2     close     5
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c("A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "B2", 
"B2", "B2", "B2", "B2", "B2", "B2", "B2", "B2"), operation = c("open", 
"open", "close", "", "open", "close", "", "open", "open", "open", 
"close", "open", "close", "open", "close")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -15L))
```

Comment: thanks, i edited dataframe in question a little but. there can be values in column "operation" like "upload" and they shouldn't have index.

Comment: and is it possible to do it with data.table?

Comment: You can ignore `'upload'` by doing `if(df$operation[i] %in% c("", "upload")) next`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a naive solution:

```
rank <- df$operation == "close" & !is.na(df$operation)
df$index <- cumsum(c(1, rank[-length(rank)]))
df$index[!df$operation %in% c("open", "close")] <- NA
df

   ID operation index
1  A1      open     1
2  A1      open     1
3  A1     close     1
4  A1      <NA>    NA
5  A1      open     2
6  A1     close     2
7  B2      <NA>    NA
8  B2      open     3
9  B2      open     3
10 B2      open     3
11 B2     close     3
12 B2      open     4
13 B2     close     4
14 B2      open     5
15 B2     close     5
```

Comment: thanks, and how to do it with data.table?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `data.table` option which perhaps helps

```
setDT(df)[
  ,
  index := ifelse(
    operation %in% c("open", "close"),
    cumsum(shift(operation == "close", fill = TRUE)),
    NA
  )
]
```

giving

```
> df
    ID operation index
 1: A1      open     1
 2: A1      open     1
 3: A1     close     1
 4: A1              NA
 5: A1      open     2
 6: A1     close     2
 7: B2              NA
 8: B2      open     3
 9: B2      open     3
10: B2      open     3
11: B2     close     3
12: B2    upload    NA
13: B2      open     4
14: B2     close     4
15: B2      open     5
16: B2     close     5
```

**Data**

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(ID = c("A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "B2",
"B2", "B2", "B2", "B2", "B2", "B2", "B2", "B2", "B2"), operation = c("open",
"open", "close", "", "open", "close", "", "open", "open", "open",
"close", "upload", "open", "close", "open", "close")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-16L))
```